# Running `sudo ./install` for MATLAB returns a permission denied error

Tags: software-installation, 17.04, matlab

While trying to install MATLAB 2016 in Ubuntu 17.04, when I type

```
sudo ./install
```

I got this error message:

```
./install: 1: eval: /home/jan/matlab2015linux/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following command:

`chmod +x /home/jan/matlab2015linux/bin/glnxa64/install_unix`

After that, try to install MATLAB again.

Good luck!